# Javascript: Trap "in" operator in proxy

Tags: javascript, arrays, es6-proxy

I have a proxy something like this:

```
var pr = new Proxy([],...);
```

Without giving all the gory details, it is set up to trap integers and return objects from another (actual) array "B" at the corresponding index.  So, eg, pr[3] would return B[3].someProperty.  It also traps "length" and returns the length of array "B".  However, values are never actually assigned directly to the pr "array".  So you see it is sort of a "pseudo" array.  It is merely reflecting array "B", and contains no actual values.

The problem comes in when the test (someinteger in pr) is run.  Of course from what I described, this test would always return false.  This test does not seem to run code in the proxy so I can't seem to trap it and compute a return for it.  Or can I?

This creates a problem with Array.prototype iterator methods because many of them perform that test.  I could write my own corresponding methods as traps in the proxy, but I would like to find a simpler way.  If there was a way to handle the "in" operator, that would save a lot of extra code.

Is there something that I am not seeing, or a way to work around this?

Comment: you could use `hasOwnProperty()` or, more naively, just check for an undefined value; underscore doesn't even check membership at all like the native implementations do, and it's gotten away with it... personally, i think the methods should use `hasOwnProperty()` instead of `in`, to avoid crap like `Array.prototype[2]="doh";Array(3).map(String)`

Comment: @dandavis: Well, I don't have control over that.  The "in" operator is what is used in the prototype methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

proxy has a trap for `in`, it is called `has`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/has

```
var a = "abcd".split("");
var pr = new Proxy(a, {
    has: function(target, prop) {
        return (prop === "length" || +prop === (prop >>> 0) && +prop < target.length);
    },

    get: function(target, prop) {
        if(prop === "length") return target.length;

        if(+prop === (prop >>> 0) && +prop < target.length)
            return target[prop];
        return void 0;
    }
});

console.log(2 in pr, pr[2]);
console.log(5 in pr, pr[5]);
```